# Convert char array to integer equivalent and vice-versa

Tags: c, string, int

I am trying to build a simple function to handle block striping onto a "fake" disk (implemented in memory as a nested array of n blocks of x bytes represented by 4 byte ints, stored to a regular file on close). Data is passed into my `write_block` function as an array of chars from the buffer in my open-file table (OFT).

In order to do this my thought process is to convert my array of chars to an integer value in blocks of 4 chars (the logic being 4x1 byte chars is equivalent to 1x4 byte integer) by using the following function:

```
//write_block(index, block_pointer)
//  write block, start with array of characters and write integers to ldisk (convBlock == converted Block)
//      return: 1 if successful, -1 if not
int write_block(int blockIndex, char *convBlock) {
    if (strlen(convBlock) > blockSize) {
        printf("Block passed to write exceeds max block size\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int i, j;
    int scalar, currIndex;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(convBlock) / sizeof(int) + ((strlen(convBlock) % sizeof(int) == 0) ? 0 : 1); i++) {
        scalar = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < sizeof(int); j++) {
            currIndex = (i * sizeof(int) + j);
            if (currIndex > strlen(convBlock))
                break;
            ldisk[blockIndex][i] += convBlock[i] * scalar;
            scalar *= 1000;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However, this doesn't work because the maximum size of an unsigned 4 bit integer is `4294967295` (10 digits), while converting a `char` array this way results in 12 digits (3 per char). I know I should technically be able to do this since a char takes up a single byte, while an integer takes 4.

My next thought was to convert to binary then convert back to an integer. However, I would need to somehow store the binary representation of 4 chars back to back which would require an integer with 4*8 = 32 digits, while the max size of the largest numeric type (`long long`) is `18446744073709551615` (20 digits).

Comment: @Rabbid76 then to convert back would you divide out multiples of 256?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear.  What are you trying to do with the blocks of data?

Comment: @chqrlie I am trying to place them in an array called ldisk initialized by `int ldisk[numBlocks][blockSize/sizeof(int)]`

Comment: OK, but why is you virtual disk composed of 4 byte `int` elements instead of bytes?  Why do you even suppose that `int` is 4 bytes, why do you use signed `int`?  How do you slice and dice the data into blocks... Your specification is missing.

Comment: Can you pass an arbitrarily long string to write_block?

Comment: @chqrlie you're correct, I meant to use `unsigned int` in my declaration. I am nowhere in my code supposing an int is 4 bytes which is why i initialize with `blockSize/sizeof(int)`, using `sizeof(int)` anywhere i want to interact with a block. It just helps to think of it as 4 bytes (which is what my system complies to) in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Does `ldisk[blockIndex] = convertedString` compile???

Comment: @barakmanos updated code, that reference was unneeded.

Comment: @Joni You *can*, but this function is invoked using my OFT buffer which is the same size as a block. If for some reason something larger is passed in, it will catch it with the first if statement.

Comment: So convBlock always has `blockSize` chars, never more or less?

Comment: @Joni No, but the memory allocated to the array passed in is of length 65 (64+null terminator)

Comment: OK, suppose convBlock has the bytes 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x03 What should this function do? Store the int 0x01000000 or the int 0x00000001?

Comment: @Joni I was assuming little endian storage

Comment: You seem to mix binary data with null terminated strings, they don't work together, don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your goal is you want to store a null terminated block of characters to a virtual disk made of integers into block `blockIndex`.

Here is a simplified version of your function that can handle different storage types: 4 byte ints or 8 byte ints:

```
#include <stdint.h>

//write_block(index, block_pointer)
//  write block, start with array of characters src and write integers to ldisk
//      return: 1 if successful, -1 if not
int write_block(int blockIndex, const char *src) {
    size_t i, j, k, size;

    size = strlen(src) + 1;  // include the null terminator in the written conversion.
    if (size > blockSize) {
        printf("Block passed to write exceeds current block size\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = j = k = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ldisk[blockIndex][j] &= ~(0xFFULL << k);
        ldisk[blockIndex][j] |= (unsigned long long)(unsigned char)src[i] << k;
        k += 8;
        if (k == sizeof(ldisk[blockIndex][j]) * 8) {
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Notes:

- I included the null terminator in the conversion so the reading code knows where to stop.
- The `char` values must be cast as `unsigned char` to avoid sign propagation in case `char` type is signed, which is the default on many systems.
- You should return the number if blocks written (`j`) to the caller. This is useful information, and can easily be distinguished from -1 for errors.
- This code **does** assume that `char` has 8 bits.  Using `CHAR_BITS` instead of `8` would allow for other values with some other constant adjustments, if you really seek full compatibility with exotic platforms.
- I use `unsigned long long` arithmetic to allow for the storage unit to be as large as possible.